# delete special named folder in public_html

Tags: php

i am new in php

i have upload all files and folders in `public_html` to live my website, i don't know what was problem there in server but `PaxHeader` named folder was automatically created in all my public_html like in css,js,admin, admin's js in every folder there is a folder named `PaxHeader` so i want to make a script for delete that folder from all `public_html` but basically i am a designer. so i know only few php code. any bodody help me for that

my folder structure is like :

```
           -public_html
              -PaxHeader
              -js
                -PaxHeader 
              -css
                 -PaxHeader
              -admin
                 -PaxHeader
                 -js
                   -PaxHeader
                 -css
                   -PaxHeader
```

this structure is just example, `PaxHeader` folder is in every folder of `public_html` and evry `PaxHeader` folder has some files, how i can delete by script of `php` ?

Comment: Can I suggest an answer using POSIX-compliant tools instead of php? You can do this with a simple `find . -type d -name 'PaxHeader' -delete` if you're on a UNIX-like system.

Comment: where to type `find -type d -name 'PaxHeader' -delete` and how to use it ?

Comment: In the `public_html` directory.

Comment: means in php file i have to write code that located in `public-html` ?

Comment: Can you log into the server via SSH? Via a command line/terminal?

Comment: i can access files by Cpenal and by cpenal's file manager

Comment: Nope, not good enough...

Comment: i have also use filezilla

Comment: Nope, you need a **command line**. Maybe that's not an option in your case, either due to technical impossibility or due to lack of UNIX skill/knowledge. In that case writing a PHP script is an option, albeit a terribly ugly workaround for a simple server administration task which is typically done on the command line. We do expect some knowledge and effort here though, just coming here and expecting people to write code for you is very much frowned upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple php code for you.

```
$basepath = "/home/mohsen/Desktop/public_html/";
$dirNameToRemove = "PaxHeader";

function findAndRemove($path)
{
    global $dirNameToRemove;

    $items = scandir($path);

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        if(!is_dir($path . $item) || $item == '.' || $item == '..')
            continue;

        if($item == $dirNameToRemove)
        {
            #remove directory
            rmdir($path . $item);
        }
        else
        {
            findAndRemove($path . $item . "/");
        }
    }
}

findAndRemove($basepath);
```

$basepath variable is a base path to your public_html directory
$dirNameToRemove variable is the name of directory you want to delete recursive.

Enjoy it!

Comment: i just added function for non empty folder

`function rm_rmdir($dir) {
   if (is_dir($dir)) {
     $objects = scandir($dir);
     foreach ($objects as $object) {
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
         if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
       }
     }
     reset($objects);
     rmdir($dir);
   }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write something like that (untested)

```
function deleteDir($dirPath) {
    if (substr($dirPath, strlen($dirPath) - 1, 1) != '/') {
        $dirPath .= '/';
    }
    $files = glob($dirPath . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            self::deleteDir($file);
        } else {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dirPath);
}
    function removepaxdir($path)  {
    $dir=opendir($path);
    while ($FileName=readdir($dir))
    {
    if(is_dir($FileName))
    {
    if($FileName=='PaxHeader') deleteDir($path.$FileName);
    else removepaxdir($path.$FileName);
    }
    }
}    

removepaxdir('.');
```